# grpc-gateway runtime version conflict

Tags: grpc-go, grpc-gateway, protobuf-go

from last few days the protoc generator is generating code with v2 version of github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway. I want to keep using github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway v1.16.0. I am unable to remove the v2 version which is causing conflict. I tried removing from go.mod, clearing from $GOPATH. I suppose my protoc generator is not able to use v1 version. Kindly guide me as how shall I sync the grpc-gateway runtime package.

Using below commands to generate the messages and service

```
protoc -I . --go-grpc_out=. api/protobuf-spec/catalog_fetch/*.proto
protoc -I . --grpc-gateway_out=logtostderr=true:. api/protobuf-spec/catalog_fetch/*.proto
```

Note: It is generating both grpc.pb.go file and pb.go file, which is further causing issue.

````
cannot use mux (type *"github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/runtime".ServeMux) as type *"github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime".ServeMux ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I have spent 3 hours debugging the exact same problem.

You have to remove the binary from your `GOPATH` and `GOROOT`.

For simplicity, just use `which protoc-gen-grpc-gateway`.

This should point you to the binary `protoc` is using under the hood. Remove it and rerun `go get -u  github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway@v1.16.0`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! that's work. 
For me, I've delete : "$gopath/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway.exe" file and 
"$gopath/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem" folder, and re install protoc-gen-grpc-gateway using tri tran minh way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed the `v2` version of the generator. Unfortunately, you cannot use `v1.16.0` with newer versions of the go protobuf generators. If you want to keep using `v1.16.0`, you can download the generator from the releases page https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/releases/tag/v1.16.0.